# How to create new class instances dynamically at runtime in python?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Imagine a (literal) stack of plates. If the stack gets too high, it
>   might topple. There- fore, in real life, we would likely start a new
>   stack when the previous stack exceeds some threshold. Implement a data
>   structure SetOfStacks that mimics this. SetOf- Stacks should be
>   composed of several stacks, and should create a new stack once the
>   previous one exceeds capacity. SetOfStacks.push() and
>   SetOfStacks.pop() should behave identically to a single stack (that
>   is, pop() should return the same values as it would if there were just
>   a single stack).  Bonus: Implement a function popAt(int index) which
>   performs a pop operation on a specific sub-stack.

So I wrote the code:

```
#!/bin/env python

from types import *

class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.capacity = 3
        self.stackscount = 0

    def create(self):
        id = self.stackscount + 1
        id = str(id) + "_stack"
        # How to create a new instance of Stack class at runtime ?
        # the __init__ must be run too.

    def push(self, item):
        if self.size() <= self.capacity:
            self.items.append(item)
        else:
            self.create()

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def popAt(self):
        pass

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

s = Stack()
s.push(10)
```

How do I create a new `s` type object dynamically at runtime?  I searched on the internet and found that using [new.instance or new.classobj](https://docs.python.org/2/library/new.html?highlight=new.instance#new.instance) is the solution but when I did so my new object did not seem to have `items` from `__init__` function. In python3, `type()` seems to be the answer but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#module-types) doesn't have any examples.

Comment: You have misunderstood the problem - where is `SetOfStacks`?

Comment: I think ultimately the problem is to:
1. create a stack class that is able to push, pop, peek methods
2. the stack class must be able to create new stack objects when a stack object it was pushing to is full.

I don't think setofstacks or stack as name for the class matters at this point.

Comment: No, the `SetOfStacks` creates a new `Stack` when the existing stacks are full. `Stack` is just responsible for refusing to accept any new items when full, `SetOfStacks` is responsible for creating additional space. The `capacity` should be the capacity of each `Stack`, not the number of stacks in the `SetOfStacks` (which is initially one and will increase as necessary).

Comment: Thank you, is this the right direction?

<code>
class SetOfStacks:
 def __init__(self):
  s = Stack()

 def create(self):
  self.stackscount = self.stackscount + 1
  stacks = [Stack()]
</code>

Comment: No, I would expect your `__init__` to contain `self.stacks = [Stack()]` (i.e. a list, currently containing a single `Stack`). Assuming `create` would be called when the last `Stack` in `self.stacks` is full, it should `.append` a new `Stack`, not create a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a parent-child relation : when a Stack is full, it creates a child and delegate next pushes to it. It could lead to :

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self, parent = None, id=None):
        self.stackscount = 0
        self.capacity = 3
        self.items = []
        self.parent = parent
        self.id = id
        self.child = None

    def create(self):
        id = self.stackscount + 1
        id = str(id) + "_stack"
        return Stack(self, id)

    def push(self, item):
        if self.size() <= self.capacity:
            self.items.append(item)
        else:
            if self.child is None:
                self.child = self.create()
            self.child.push(item)

    def pop(self):
        if self.child is not None:
            item = self.child.pop()
            if len(self.child.items) == 0:
                self.child = None
        else:
            item = self.items.pop()
        return item

    def popAt(self):
        pass

    def peek(self):
        if self.child is not None:
            item = self.child.peek()
        else:
            item = self.items[len(self.items)-1]
        return item

    def size(self):
        l = len(self.items)
        if self.child is not None:
            l += self.child.size()
        return l

s = Stack()
s.push(10)
```

`popAt` is still to be implemented, but I tested it and it correctly creates new stacks when pushing and empties and removes them when popping.

The implementation of `popAt` will require some evolutions to current `pop` implementation, to allow removing an intermediate stack :

```
def pop(self):
    if self.child is not None:
        item = self.child.pop()
        if len(self.child.items) == 0:
            self.child = self.child.child
            if self.child is not None:
                self.child.parent = self
    else:
        item = self.items.pop()
    return item

def popAt(self, stacknumber):
    s = self
    for i in range(stacknumber):
        s = s.child
        if s is None:
            return None
    if len(s.items) == 0:
        return None
    item = s.items.pop()
    if len(s.items) == 0 and s.parent is not None:
        s.parent.child = s.child
        if s.child is not None:
            s.child.parent = s.parent
    return item
```

Comment: Thanks for this! How do I see all children at once? I tried:

[200]: s.child.child.items      
Out[200]: [5]

In [201]: s.child.items
Out[201]: [3, 4]

In [202]: s.items
Out[202]: [1, 2]

Comment: In this implementation, you cannot see all children at once, since each Stack has only one child. Is's more like a double linked list.

Answer (score 2):

You've confused yourself by referring to a "type object". In Python that means the class itself, not its instances.

To create new `Stack` objects, simply do what you're already doing: call the `Stack` class. You can append them to a list:

```
stacks = [Stack() for _ in range(5)]
```

However, as jon points out, that won't solve your problem since you haven't defined the SetOfStacks class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I see what you did there. That's exactly what I wanted to do. Your code is simple and clear. So `stacks` is a list of Stack() objects, right?

Answer (score 1):

The `type()` function is indeed what you are looking for. Documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

You can call it like this:

```
# Bases is a tuple of parent classes to inherit
bases = Stack,

# Dict contains extra properties for the class, for example if you want to add a class variable or function
dict_ = {}

# Construct the class
YourClass = type('YourClass', bases, dict_)

# Create an instance of the class
your_instance = YourClass()
```

It looks like you are just looking at instance creation though:

```
class Stack(object):

    def create(self):
        id = self.stackscount + 1
        id = str(id) + "_stack"
        # How to create a new instance of Stack class at runtime ?
        # the __init__ must be run too.
        stack = Stack()
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! I don't understand the part `Yourclass = type('YourClass', bases, dict_)` and then `your_instance = YourClass()`. To me it looks like am creating a new class based off my Stack class. Can I not just create a new object (an instance) of Stack class directly?

Comment: @sindhus: the second example shows you to create instances. The first how to create new classes :)